# ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object; When adding a float variable to my features (X) dataframe. Logistic Regression statsmodels

Tags: pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I have a very simple dataframe that looks like this:

```
   A      B     C  Constant  
0 True  False True True
1 False False True True
2 ................. True
3 ................
4 etc
5
6
```

I have added a constant column to the dataframe.

I'm trying to predict a binary (0/1) y value.

```
log_reg_traits = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()
log_reg_traits.summary()
```

This works perfectly! However, when I add a column filled with floats to the X dataframe.

```
    A  B  C  D Constant
0. Tr Fls Tr 14.0 True.
```

The exact same code stops working and throws the following error:
`ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).`
There are no NA values in the dataframe.

Reproducible example:

```
X = pd.DataFrame([[True, False, 12.3], [False, True, 14.2], [False, False, 18.0]])
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 0])

log_reg = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()
log_reg.summary()
```

When you remove the floats from the `X` frame it works but when you leave them in they crash.

What is going on here and how to fix this?

Comment: Look at `X.to_numpy()`.  In one case till be 2d with a `bool` dtype, all values True/False.  In ther other it will be `object` dtype, with a mix of bool and float.  I don't know what `sm.Logit` expects, but it looks like this mix of types is giving it problems.  Have you reread its docs?